# How to add multiple files uisng reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here i'm trying to add multiple files to upload, but it is replacing in to new one and the response value is also showing empty. i dont understand what i'm doing wrong here thanks in advance

```
const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState('');
const [fileImage, setFileImage] = React.useState([]);

const handleChange = (event) => {
 setQuestion(event.target.value);
}

const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
 setFileImage(event.target.files);
}

addQuizDetails() {
  const Questions = question;
  const fileImages = fileImage;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  }
  var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", fileImages);
    formData.append("question",question )
    axios
    .post("http://localhost:4000/api/quiz/addQuiz",formData,headers)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.message) {
        alert(response.data.message)
      }
      else {
        alert("failed")
      }
  })
 }
}


 <TextField className={classes.content} onChange={handleChange} label="Question" variant="outlined" />
          <input 
            type="file" 
            onChange={handleSelectChange}
            multiple />
          <div className={classes.button}>
            <Button className={classes.submit} variant="contained" onClick={addQuizDetails}>Submit</Button>           
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code by using spread operator for array:

```
const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files
    setFileImage([...fileImage, ...selectedFiles]);
}
```